# jquery update border color without overwriting border-left-color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have element with this css:

```
border: 20px solid;
border-color:#4ea88e;
border-right-width: 10px; 
border-left-color: transparent;
```

I want to update with javascript border-color without overwriting border-left-color. Is that possible without hacks? If I try this:

```
$("#myElement").css('border-color','#ffffff')
```

It will update also border-left-color.

Comment: Why not just update border-right, border-top, and border-bottom? I typed it rather easily here.

Comment: To minimize frontend code. It is part of more complex code because elements gets different colors based on color picker changes from another elements.

Comment: That is a micro-optimization.

Comment: It is not micro-optimization because real case is much more complicated, it involves color pickers, applying css rules from element A to different css rules into different elements, ... I gave just a simple example.

Comment: Then you have oversimplified your example.

Answer (score 1):

Use normal class attributes - jQuery's `.css` isn't that great with performance.

```
$("#myElement").addClass("datBorder");
```

CSS:

```
.datBorder {
    border-color: #4ea88e;
    border-left-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an object in `.css()`

```
$("#myElement").css({
        'border-top-color': '#000',
        'border-top-style': 'solid',
        'border-right-style': 'solid',
        'border-bottom-style': 'solid',
        'border-right-color': '#abc',
        'border-bottom-color': 'green',
    });
```

**See Example below**

```js
$('#test').on('click', function () {
        $("#myElement").css({
            'border-top-color': '#000',
            'border-top-style': 'solid',
            'border-right-style': 'solid',
            'border-bottom-style': 'solid',
            'border-right-color': '#abc',
            'border-bottom-color': 'green',
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="test">Test</button>
<div id="myElement" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: yellow"></div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't resolve my problem. In your example you apply different borders. In my case I apply single border-color which overrides border-left-color. This is my problem, question is how to applying border-color without overriding border-left-color.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
var orgBorderColor= $("#myElement").css("border-color");
$("#myElement").css('border-color','#ffffff');
$("#myElement").css('border-left-color',orgBorderColor);
```

Answer (score -1):

Easy little trick with css

```
#el {
   border: 20px solid;
   border-color:#4ea88e;
   border-right-width: 10px; 
   border-left-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Edit: I don't understand how this is not working:

```
$(document).ready(
   $('#el').css('border-color','#111'); // or any other color for that matter
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6rk08kfL/

I don't condone the abuse of the `!impotant` since it may not always be considered as a must but often times, applying a different style to a smaller group of a certain class of elements should be possible.

Therefore I think the `!important` rule here comes in handy when overriding the style changes made by JavaScript.

Comment: 1) not working because inline styles have higher precendence 2) don't abuse `!important` for this.

Comment: Even if both styles were inline it will still override !important rule in the above case.

Comment: @Christoph I guess I've missunderstood or I'm missing out on something here, since I think the `!impotant` comes in handy when overriding the style changes made by JavaScript, that way I don't think we're abusing the tag for that matter. note I've also editted my answer with a fiddle.

Comment: The problem I have with `!important` is that it breaks the cascading nature of css, and thus may lead to huge problems, especially in large applications... I revoked my -1 since I weirdly was wrong about the precedence of inline over important external rules, but I won't give a +1 for the reasons above.

Comment: @Christoph I can't disagree.